# IntPtr to String and long?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, marshalling

I am using C# and the .NET 2.0 framework.

I have this method here to get a string out of a `IntPtr`:

```
 void* cfstring = __CFStringMakeConstantString(StringToCString(name));
        IntPtr result = AMDeviceCopyValue_Int(device, unknown, cfstring);
        if (result != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            byte length = Marshal.ReadByte(result, 8);
            if (length > 0)
            {
                string s = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new IntPtr(result.ToInt64() + 9L), length);
                return s;
            }
        }
        return String.Empty;
```

It works and all data which is saved as string in my USB-Device (return data of method `AMDeviceCopyValue`).

Now I get this:

> £\rº\0\0Â¨\t\0\0\0ˆ\0\0\0\0\0\0x>Ô\0\0\0\0Å¨\t\0\0\0€1ÔxÕÍ¸MÔ\0\0\0\0È¨\t\0\0\0€)\0fŒ\a\0Value\0\0Ë¨\t\0\0\0€7fŒ\a\0Result\0Î¨\t\0\0\0ˆTÅfŒ\a\0\0Key\0\0\0\0ñ¨\t\0\0\0€+fŒ\a\0Port\0\0\0ô¨\t\0\0\0€%fŒ\a\0Key\0\0\0\0÷¨\t\0\0\0€:\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ú¨\t\0"

This is saved as `long` - so, how I can get this `IntPtr` into `long` and not `string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to read a long instead of a string, use:

```
long l = Marshal.ReadInt64(result, 9);
return l;
```

Comment: Sadly not what I want... =( I don't know why, your solution seems right

Comment: I answered to the question: `how I can get this IntPtr into long and not string` - extracts the long at address being pointed at by result + offset 9. So what **do** you want exactly? I really do not know what datastructure `AMDeviceCopyValue_Int` returns so I cannot help you in that regard. Are you even using the correct function for extracting `long`?

Comment: this is the same procedure whioch is solved in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254602/convert-a-method-from-java-to-c-net

But not I must solve it or convert this method to c#.net

Comment: What is the memory structure of `this` (in your linked question)? From a quick google search, it seems that `AMDeviceCopyValue_Int` returns a pointer to string (`CFString`). Your questions are very foggy and inaccurate.