# Convert a method from java to C#.net

Tags: c#, java

I have a method in Java:

```
public int getInt() {
IntByReference ibr = new IntByReference();
if (CFLib.INSTANCE.CFNumberGetValue(this, 4, ibr))
  return ibr.getValue();
return -1;  }
```

here is the Reference:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNumberRef/Reference/reference.html

How I Can copy this exactly for C#.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That 4 there corresponds to the enum value `kCFNumberSInt64Type`.  Why was that being jammed into a (32 bit) integer?  Anyway, it looks like `CFNumberGetValue` wants a `void*` (C++) for its third parameter.

```
public int getInt() {
    int i;
    if (CFLib.INSTANCE.CFNumberGetValue(this, kCFNumberSInt32Type, (IntPtr)i))
        return i;
    return -1;
}
```

I don't know if anything needs to be done with the first parameter as I have no idea what `this` is.

Comment: The Problem is, there is no CFLib in C#, so i must find another method to do it.
"This" is the value, which should be converted

Comment: If you're not going to use the Core Foundation library then just replace all CFNumber references and calls with equivalent C# primitives.  It this case it looks like your entire class (whatever `this` is) should be replaced by an int (or `long`).